# Selectively Filtering Across Multiple Variables in R

Tags: r, filter

I'm using Tidyverse

```
animals <- c("Bat", "Monkey", "Tiger", "Frog", "Bald Eagle")
Type <- c("mammal","mammal","mammal", "Amphibian", "Bird")
Quantity <- c(8, 5, 1, 5, 1)
Bananas <-  c(0,1,0,0,0)
Apples <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
Crickets <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
DF <- data.frame(animals, Type, Quantity,Bananas, Apples, Crickets)

#DF looks like this 
     animals      Type Quantity Bananas Apples Crickets
1       Bat     mammal        8       1      1        0
2     Monkey    mammal        5       1      1        0
3      Tiger    mammal        1       0      0        0
4       Frog    Amphibian     5       0      0        1
5 Bald Eagle    Bird          1       0      0        0
```

I'm looking for a simple way to filter for a result that shows:

1. only rows that are mammals and
2. only rows where Bananas, OR Apples, OR Crickets are equal to 1

```
#desired results
  animals   Type Quantity Bananas Apples Crickets
1    Bat  mammal        8       0      0        1
2  Monkey mammal        5       1      1        0
```

I've been trying to use filter_all(any_vars) and do conditions, but in the instances where it kind of worked, I'm still having Tiger show up on the final list, due to it having "1" in the quantity variable.

I need a clean way to do this filtering, I don't want to lose any columns, in the real dataset there are 50 columns of other info that need to be kept.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *inclusive OR* for your constraint 2, then

```r
DF %>%
  filter(
    Type == "mammal",
    rowSums(select(., Bananas:Crickets) == 1) > 0
  )
#   animals   Type Quantity Bananas Apples Crickets
# 1     Bat mammal        8       0      0        1
# 2  Monkey mammal        5       1      1        0
```

Comment: that solves my needs, is there an easy explanation for the " > 0" at the end of the line? I'm not sure what that does (still figuring a lot of this stuff out)

Comment: `rowSums` operates on matrices (and converts frames to them), and its return value is a *number* (the sum across each row). Even though the call inside of `rowSums` returns logical, we're looking for rows where *one or more* columns are true; one might also do `apply(select(...), 1, any)` for the same results, though `rowSums` is faster (if speed is a concern). Ultimately, `dplyr::filter` needs `logical`, and `rowSums(.) > 0` provides that.

Answer (score 1):

filtering twice should work, using the | operator for the second call.

```r
DF %>%
    filter(Type == "mammal", Bananas == 1 | Apples == 1 | Crickets == 1)
```

More explicitly, in two separate filter calls:

```r
DF %>%
    filter(Type == "mammal") %>%
    filter(Bananas == 1 | Apples == 1 | Crickets == 1)
```